# Pass multiple list to CMake without a splitting keyword

Tags: list, macros, cmake

I need to pass several lists to an own `add_executable` macro. These lists are used in this macro. The code looks like this:

```
set(LIST_FILES
  foo.cpp
  bar.cpp
)

set(LIST_LIBRARIES
 libpng
 libfancy
)

add_own_executable(fancyfoobar ${LIST_FILES} ${LIST_LIBRARIES})

# The CMake macro
macro(add_own_executable target files libraries)
  # Do stuff
endmacro()
```

The problem is, that `target` has the value "fancyfoobar" (OK), but the parameter list is a single list item and not the whole list, means `files` have the value foo.cpp (NOT OK). ?`libraries` will have the value bar.cpp (NOT OK).

Is there a way to pass a "list" as a list and not in a way, that are items are appended. I think I have to introduce keywords, so I can iterate over all items and know when files/libraries are starting - is there a way to avoid such an "annoying solution" like this:

```
add_own_executable(fancyfoobar FILES ${LIST_FILES} LIBRARIES ${LIST_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to pass the lists with double quotes:

```
add_own_executable(fancyfoobar "${LIST_FILES}" "${LIST_LIBRARIES}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since [CMake macros](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html) perform a single-level of text replacement, one way to pass lists to a macro is to actually pass the names of lists and then inside the macro double dereference the lists.

For example:

Your macro:

```
macro(add_own_executable target files libs)
  add_executable(${target} ${${files}})
  target_link_libraries(${target} ${${libs}})
endmacro()
```

Usage:

```
set(LIST_FILES
  foo.cpp
  bar.cpp
)

set(LIST_LIBRARIES
  libpng
  libfancy
)

add_own_executable(fancyfoobar LIST_FILES LIST_LIBRARIES)
```

In this example, the call `add_own_executable(fancyfoobar LIST_FILES LIST_LIBRARIES)` would become equivalent to

```
add_executable(fancyfoobar ${LIST_FILES})
target_link_libraries(fancyfoobar ${LIST_LIBRARIES})
```

as CMake would do a single text replace for every occurrence of `${target}`, `${files}`, and `${libs}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach-it the argument given in the macro to form another list, is not intuitive but It'll serve as workaround:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project ("dummy" VERSION "1.0" LANGUAGES C)

set (
    _FILES
        hello.c
        world.c
)

macro(show_them)
    set (TMP)
    foreach (ITEM ${ARGV})
        set (TMP "${TMP} ${ITEM}")
    endforeach ()
    message ("- Your list: [${TMP}]")
endmacro ()


show_them (${_FILES})
```